# Click Button or Link to open Drop Drown Like Google

Tags: jquery, html, css

I trying to find a drop down like Google Search Setting Drop Down

here is the Sample image :

[image]

Is There any Demos like that So that I can use in my website or way to build this ? I just need the basic functionalists , Click the Button/link to open Drop Down . I can give the Style . I am bad in jquery and that's way finding it difficult to make .

If is there any Solution that would be Great .

Comment: the image path given by you is saying blockpage

Comment: +1 for the "Drop Drown" :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using the `.toggle()` function to show and hide it on click of the gear.

```
$(function(){
    $('#gear').click(function(){
       $('#dropdown').toggle(); 
    });
});
```

[Simple demo (click the box)](http://jsfiddle.net/58kBY/)

Comment: This is Perfect . I can modify this for my Use . Thank you So much

Comment: Can you Help me With another Function . IT is When I click any other place Drop Down Should Goes away . Is this Possible with any function ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [twitter bootstrap drop down menu](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/components.html#dropdowns).

Answer (score 0):

```
try this.

**html**
<div id="drop">drop<div id="dropdown"><a>xxxxxxx</a><hr/><a>yyyyyyyy</a><hr/><a>zzzzzzz</a></div></div>

**css**

#drop {
    margin: auto;
    width: 40px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 2px solid ;
    position: relative;
   background-color:green;
    border-radius:4px;
    cursor:pointer;
    }

#dropdown {
    position:absolute;
    top: 30px;
    right: -1px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid;
    display: none;
    text-align:center;
     border-radius:4px;
    cursor:pointer;
}

**script**

$(function(){
    $('#drop').click(function(){
       $('#dropdown').toggle(); 
    });
});
```